# How to show the introduction text of the PHP internal web server

Tags: php

I actually launch a PHP web internal web server with the command `php -S localhost:8000 -t myPath myFile.php` via a PHP file.

What I want to see :

> PHP 7.3.11-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 Development Server started at Mon Nov 18 12:04:52 2019
>
> Listening on http://localhost:8000
>
> Document root is /var/www/html/perso/otra/web
>
> Press Ctrl-C to quit.

When I type this command in the terminal it shows those informations but not when it comes from my script.

I see nothing. All I succeeded to do is put this output into a file when I *stop* the server via Ctrl+C by using the `proc_open` function.

I want to show those informations and ... :

- instantly not at the end of the program ...
- not in a file but directly to the terminal screen

What is the simplest way to achieve this ?

I tried different functions `exec`, `system`, `passthru`, `popen` and `proc_open` but I do not master the last ones. Here is an example of what I tried with `proc_open` :

```php
<?php
define('STD_IN', 0);
define('STD_OUT', 1);
define('STD_ERR', 2);
$process = proc_open(
  'php -S localhost:8000 -t ' . BASE_PATH . 'web/ ' . CORE_PATH . 'console/localServerInit.php',
  [
    STD_IN => ['pipe', 'r'],
    STD_OUT => ['pipe', 'w'],
    STD_ERR => ['file', BASE_PATH . 'logs/dev/localServerError.txt', 'a']
  ],
  $pipes,
  __DIR__,
  $_ENV
);

if (is_resource($process) === true)
{
  stream_set_blocking($pipes[0], 0);
  stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);

  echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
  fclose($pipes[0]);
  fclose($pipes[1]);

  $return_value = proc_close($process);
  echo "The commands returned $return_value", PHP_EOL;
}
```

`echo` does not print anything. If I use a file for the `STD_OUT` instead, I will see the content when I type Ctrl+C.

Comment: *"but not when it comes from my script"* – You'll have to clarify what exactly your script does…

Comment: It does exactly the  same thing... `passthru('php -S localhost:8000 -t web/ ' . CORE_PATH . 'console/localServerInit.php'); ` is an example of what I have tested.

Comment: why do you want to do this, when you could just run the command from the terminal directly anyway? I'm struggling to understand the purpose of wrapping it in a PHP script, especially if you're just going to execute that PHP from a terminal window.

Comment: P.S. you mention that "echo does not print anything". Are you certain that "echo" is even happening? Have you verified that `is_resource($process) === true` returns true, for instance? And have you got PHP error reporting switched on?

Comment: I edited my post. I see if I have errors in a file so I have no problems on this side. In reality, I have more code in my PHP. I ask to my user if he wants to generate this web server in order to test the route I just created in my framework.

Comment: Ok but you didn't answer my question about the result of the is_resource command and the echo

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. Yes, I have tested it, an `echo '*';` between the condition block about `is_resource($process) === true` shows `*` correctly.